# Float right all elements inside div to be in one line horizontally

Tags: html, css

I would like to float right all elements inside `div` (text, picture and button) to be in one line horizontally using CSS. How can I achieve it?

`.log {float: right;}` floats them all as one element to the right but vertically.

EDIT: 
What I have:

```
img
txt
button
```

`float: right` works like :

```
                                                                       img
                                                                       txt
                                                                       button
```

What I want:

```
                                                                 img text button
```

My code:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$st = $_SESSION['status'];
$fileNameNew = $_SESSION['fileName'];

echo '<div class="log">';
if($st == 0){
    echo "<img style='width:50px;height:50px;' src='includes/uploads/".$fileNameNew."?".mt_rand()."'>";
    echo "<p>Witaj : " .$_SESSION['uid'];
    echo "</p>";
}else{
    echo '<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="includes/uploads/default.png">';
}
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo '<form action="includes/logout.php">
        <button class="logout" type="submit">Wyloguj się</button>
    </form>';
}else{
    header("Location: index.php");              
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking - floating always works on the horizontal axis. Do you want to `clear` the float maybe ...?

Comment: @CBroe I "drew" what I would like to achive :)

Comment: `p` is a block element, of course it goes onto a new line. You need to float the elements _inside_ your `.log` container element.

Comment: i find it easier to achieve this with a single div that is floated right with center text alignment, and the contents are just nested within that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to float `.log`, you want to float the individual elements. But floating them right will also reverse the order they appear in. You can either reverse the order of the elements in your HTML, then float right.

```
.log img, .log p, .log form {
  float: right;
}
```

Or you can use flexbox. Flexbox will lay the children out horizontally. I recommend this if your user base is using > ie9

```
.log {
  display: flex;
}
```

making the children `inline-block` will also lay them out horizontally

```
.log img, .log p, .log form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) I have used `.log { float: right; }` and `.log img, .log p, .log form { display: inline-block;}` and it worked.